# Software center no longer shows software categories in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-center

When I purchased my Dell Precision with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Dell technicians assisted me with initial setup. At that time the Software Center displayed "Editor's Picks", and below those the categories of software available to choose from to install. Somewhere along the line, the categories vanished. I perform regular updates on my laptop, but am baffled about why available software categories no longer appear. Does antbody know a solution to this issue? Thanks in advance.